# Problema con propiedad disabled

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un juego con un sistema de ayudas (palabra, sonido o tema). Cada vez que cliqueo un boton, me deberia mostrar el contenido y a su vez desabilite los otros dos botones. Mi codigo:

```
  function mostrarImagen(){
  document.getElementById('imagen_pista').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('palabra').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('sonido').disabled=true;
}
function mostrarPalabra(){
  document.getElementById('palabra_pista').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('imagen').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('sonido').disabled=true;
}

function escucharPista(){
  document.getElementById('audio').play();
  document.getElementById('imagen').disabled=true;
  document.getElementById('palabra').disabled=true;
}
```

Solo funciona la funcion de mostrarPalabra. Las otras dos me desabilita solo uno de los dos botones y no puedo ver el error. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Asegúrate de que los id sean los correctos.

Comment: ya chequee y lo son